# How can I use a select2 selectbox with dataTables?

Tags: jquery, datatables, jquery-select2

I want to use a select2 selectbox inside my bootstrap datatable. I need to use the [full select2 js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.full.js) But it is not working and I am wondering why.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        scrollY:        "300px",
        scrollX:        true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        paging:         false,
        fixedColumns:   {
            leftColumns: 1,
            rightColumns: 1
        }
    } );
} );

$("#e1").select2();
```

```css
td, th{background-color:white;}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.2/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.2/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.full.js"></script>


<table id="example" class="stripe row-border order-column" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>E-mail</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><select  id="e1">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
        <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
        <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select></td>
                <td>Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
                <td>5407</td>
                <td>a.satou@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. You are using a CSS **`3.2`** version along with a **`4.0.3`** version of the libray! Since version 4 is a complete rewrite any UI will fail. Find matching versions [here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/select2).
2. You need to instantiate select2 *after* dataTables is initialised. You can do that in the `drawCallback` callback.
3. Do not use `id`'s to reference the select2's. I guess you will have a lot of select2's on multiple pages, so give them a dummy class like `dt-select2` so you can initialise all visible select2's in one call. But by all mean preserve the `id`'s for reference in event handlers.

Example :

```
$('#example').DataTable({
  ...
  drawCallback: function() {
     $('.dt-select2').select2();
  }
})
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u91javfy/)

Comment: hey @peace_love, what do you mean by "the toolbar"?

Comment: @peace_love  You must target the specific element, try with `$('.dataTables_length select').select2()` instead -> **http://jsfiddle.net/349kL0pu/**

Answer (score 1):

See this example include a `select` option on a header to [filter the data](https://jsfiddle.net/73zawd5b/5/#&togetherjs=fgu5BihnA7):

demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/73zawd5b/5/#&togetherjs=fgu5BihnA7)

```
$('#example').DataTable({
  initComplete: function() {
    this.api().columns('.fName').every(function() {
      var column = this;
      var select = $('<select class="f"><option value="">First Name</option></select>')
        .appendTo($(column.header()).empty())
        .on('change', function() {
          var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
            $(this).val()
          );

          column
            .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
            .draw();
        });

      column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
        select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
      });
    });
    this.api().columns('.lName').every(function() {
      var column = this;
      var select = $('<select class="f"><option value="">Last Name</option></select>')
        .appendTo($(column.header()).empty())
        .on('change', function() {
          var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
            $(this).val()
          );

          column
            .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
            .draw();
        });

      column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
        select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
      });
    });
  }


})
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.f').select2();
});
```

Comment: demo is super! thank you @Glorfindel is there a way to add a select2 to all columns? not just on first and last name?

Comment: @WallaboutProgramming The only thing I did to this answer is *have my script* fix the broken link, I haven't even read it. The author hasn't been active since they wrote this answer, so I think you'd better ask a new question.